# What is the difference between domain randomization and data augmentation?

Tags: neural-network, dataset, variance, data-augmentation, simulation

Domain randomization (https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06907) is used to create a synthetic dataset with enough variance that it will encompass unseen real data, as just one variation.

I am trying to understand how this is different from applying data augmentation techniques to a synthetically generated dataset.

Comment: "domain randomization" strikes me as a special kind of data augmentation.  A kind of difference is that data augmentation seeks to expand the training data to include invariances you expect/know are there.  Where the domain randomization approach kind-of "overwhelms" the network with all kinds of "irrelevant" variability that it's "forced" (hopefully) to learn the relevant things.  In that paper, how to detect objects.